# userlist of a specific role in the discord (Python)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I would like to have a command to get a list of ALL users with a special role.
But this doesn't really work.

Everything is output, but not the members.
Does anyone here have an idea what this is about? Or even a better alternative?

Many thanks in advance

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord import message
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

class ClansCog(commands.Cog, name='Clans'):
                             
        def __init__(self, bot):
            self.bot = bot
        
        @commands.command(pass_context=True)
        async def deutsch(self, ctx, *args):

            if ctx.channel.type is not discord.ChannelType.private:
                await ctx.message.delete()

            roll_id = 733988944--------
            guild_id = 71911198261------

            guild = self.bot.get_guild(guild_id)
            partner_role = guild.get_role(roll_id)

            print(partner_role.members)
            print(partner_role.id)
            print(client.guilds)
                                         
def setup(bot):
        bot.add_cog(ClansCog(bot))
        print('Clans loaded!')
```

From Terminal

```
[]
733988944533-------
[]
```

Comment: This is perhaps the command you are looking for:  
 https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role.members  
. It is in the object role and it's output is to retrieve a list with all of the members that have that role (returns member object)

Comment: But I use that here:

print(partner_role.members)

Because here I assign the role to the variable or not? 

partner_role = guild.get_role(roll_id)

Comment: I suppose that if you made the intents all then you approved the server members intent as well as the presence data intent on the discord dev portal just to make sure(if you don't have them approved there as well you probably can't see member objects from some variables.    Also it seems that your bot doesn't detect itself in any server for some reason, I am not sure what could fix it but perhaps that could be your main problem of why it doesn't give you member roles(but it doesn't show you errors so I'm not sure)

Comment: Privileged Gateway Intents are both on. (discord.com/developers)
And intents are in the code.

Answer (score 0):

A friend and I found the problem.
It was an intents problem (thanks Shnap :) )

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='d!'.lower(), case_insensitive=True, intents=intents)
```

**intents=intents** was missing, after that no more problem